# Excluding complete days without a specific value

Tags: r

I have data frame in R, which looks as follows:

| quotedate | days |
| --- | --- |
| 2002-01-01 | 12 |
| 2002-01-01 | 22 |
| 2002-01-01 | 32 |
| 2002-01-01 | 42 |
| 2002-01-03 | 2 |
| 2002-01-03 | 5 |
| 2002-01-03 | 12 |
| 2002-01-03 | 21 |
| 2002-01-05 | 12 |
| 2002-01-05 | 212 |
| 2002-01-05 | 32 |
| 2002-01-05 | 142 |
| 2002-01-07 | 112 |
| 2002-01-07 | 122 |
| 2002-01-07 | 132 |
| 2002-01-07 | 142 |

How can I exclude days, which have not 30 days within their days' range.

In the above exapmle I want to keep 2002-01-01 and 2002-01-05.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by “days, which have not 30 days within their days' range”?  The example you’ve shown doesn’t help clarify the meaning: why is 2002-01-07 not included in the output? It has lots of days. Even 2002-01-03 cumulatively has >30 days.

Comment: sorry for the misleading formulation. 
By days range I mean the min(days) to max(days) for every quotedate. Then I want to keep the quotedate if 30 is in this range. For example for 2002-01-01 the range would be: 12 to 42 days, so I want to keep this quotedate. For 2002-01-03: 2 to 21 days so 30 isn't part of it and I want to exclude 2002-01-03. For 2002-01-07 the range is: 112 - 142 days and 30 is no part of this range. So I want to exclude 2002-01-07.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by` and `filter`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(quotedate) %>%
  filter(max(days) >= 30)

    quotedate days
1  2002-01-01   12
2  2002-01-01   22
3  2002-01-01   32
4  2002-01-01   42
5  2002-01-05   12
6  2002-01-05  212
7  2002-01-05   32
8  2002-01-05  142
9  2002-01-07  112
10 2002-01-07  122
11 2002-01-07  132
12 2002-01-07  142
```

Comment: Thank you! That helps for the quotedates with observations only below 30. I try to turn this around, so it also works for quotedays with observations only above 30 days.

Comment: I edit the answer to use group_by and filter, I think its more concise this way

Answer (score 1):

Creating a boolean subset using `max` in `ave`.

```
dat[with(dat, ave(days, quotedate, FUN=max) >= 30), ]
#     quotedate days
# 1  2002-01-01   12
# 2  2002-01-01   22
# 3  2002-01-01   32
# 4  2002-01-01   42
# 9  2002-01-05   12
# 10 2002-01-05  212
# 11 2002-01-05   32
# 12 2002-01-05  142
# 13 2002-01-07  112
# 14 2002-01-07  122
# 15 2002-01-07  132
# 16 2002-01-07  142
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(quotedate = c("2002-01-01", "2002-01-01", "2002-01-01", 
"2002-01-01", "2002-01-03", "2002-01-03", "2002-01-03", "2002-01-03", 
"2002-01-05", "2002-01-05", "2002-01-05", "2002-01-05", "2002-01-07", 
"2002-01-07", "2002-01-07", "2002-01-07"), days = c(12L, 22L, 
32L, 42L, 2L, 5L, 12L, 21L, 12L, 212L, 32L, 142L, 112L, 122L, 
132L, 142L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```